# Textfields in Tableview behave differently on iOS 9 and iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My TableViewController uses auto-drawing custom cells with textfields and segmented controls. The textfields are selectable on iOS 10 and 11, and the keyboard pops up automatically. However, on iOS 9, the textfields returns no response upon tap, nor do the segmented controls. The app isn't frozen though, as everything else works just fine.

I'm using Xcode 9 and Swift 3.2. There's no error message from the console when textfields aren't responding on iOS 9.

Comment: may be your textfield overlapped by any other view. Check it will "Debug View Hierarchy" tool of XCode.

Comment: This is very helpful. It appears that there's a TableViewCell content view at the front of every cell on ios 9 devices, whereas on ios 10 there's none. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the same thing happened to me... and the solution is..
select simulator.
go to **hardware**>>**keyboard**

then select all three opions and after that unselect those all.
thats it!!!

i thik this is the bug of simulator... but thats fix my problem.

[image]